# How to use .clone() in a loop or for each array element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason I have to modify template of the software I use for creating invoices. Invoices are generated in html, therefore, I think that I can do that with Stylish and Grease Monkey (no support from a developer so I have to do this myself).
Basically I have some div elements and tables with no id. I have generated unique id for each element (this part of code works) and what I need now is to clone "#order-"+index+"-details" and prepend it "#order"+index+"lines" where index of "#order-"+index+"-details" matches "#order"+index+"lines" (this part does not).
I know that code is amateur and ugly, but it does not have to be efficient - it must works ;).

```
var orders=document.querySelectorAll("div.pages");
    for(var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++){

$("body").find("div.pages").each(function(index){
$(this).attr("id","order-"+index+"-page");
})

$("body").find("div.pages > div:nth-child(1) > table:nth- 
child(3)").each(function(index){
$(this).attr("id","order-"+index+"-details");
})

$("body").find("div.pages > div:nth-child(1) > table:nth- 
child(7)").each(function(index){
$(this).attr("id","order-"+index+"-lines");
})

$order_details = $("#order-"+index+"-details").clone();
$("#order"+index+"lines").prepend($order_details);

}
```

This part does not work

```
$order_details = $("#order-"+index+"-details").clone();
$("#order-"+index+"-lines").prepend($order_details);
```

It works when I am trying:

```
$order_details = $("#order-1-details").clone();
$("#order-1-lines").prepend($order_details);

$order_details = $("#order-2-details").clone();
$("#order-2-lines").prepend($order_details);
```

But I need to loop it. Many thanks in advance for all suggestions.

Regards,
Thomas.

Comment: There are too many positions within the DOM to give an accurate answer without knowing the HTML, Please post HTML and read [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$order_details = $("#order-"+index+"-details").clone();
$("#order"+index+"lines").prepend($order_details);
```

Should be

```
$order_details = $("#order-"+i+"-details").clone();
$("#order"+i+"lines").prepend($order_details);
```

It's much more clear if the code is formatted:

```
var orders = document.querySelectorAll("div.pages");
for (var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {

    $("body").find("div.pages").each(function(index) {
        $(this).attr("id","order-"+index+"-page");
    });

    $("body").find("div.pages > div:nth-child(1) > table:nth- 
    child(3)").each(function(index){
        $(this).attr("id","order-"+index+"-details");
    });

    $("body").find("div.pages > div:nth-child(1) > table:nth- 
    child(7)").each(function(index){
        $(this).attr("id","order-"+index+"-lines");
    });

    $order_details = $("#order-"+i+"-details").clone();
    $("#order"+i+"lines").prepend($order_details);

}
```